# Lagrange's theorem to prove $b^{p-1}=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My problem:

(a) Let $p$ be a prime and let $b$ be a nonzero element of the field $Z_p$. Show that $b^{p-1}=1$.
Hint: Lagrange.

(b) Use (a) to prove that if $p$ is a prime and $a$ is an integer then $p$ divides $a^p-a$. This result is known as Fermat’s Little Theorem.

Well I might have an idea for (a) without lagrange's theorem, but I want to see how I can use Lagrange's theorem to deal with (a). I cannot see directly how I can use the theorem. I'm using the book: Abstract Algebra An Introduction 3rd ediition by Hungerford.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $p$ is a prime  $Z_p-\{0\}$ endowed with the multiplication is a group of order $p-1$ thus for every $a\in Z_p$ the order $a_p$ of $gr(a)$ the group generated by $a$ divides $p-1$ (Lagrange), we deduce that $p-1=qa_p$, and $a^{p-1}=(a^{a_p})^q=1$.

$a^{p-1}=1$ if $a\neq 0$, $aa^{p-1}=a.1$

Answer (score 2):

Given p prime, set of units $\mathbb{Z}_p^×$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ forms a multiplicative group of order (p-1). If $b$ is some non-zero element in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, then $b$ is a unit and hence, $ b\in \mathbb{Z}_p^×$. By Lagrange's theorem, $b^{(p-1)}=1.\\$
If $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p^×$, then $a^{p-1}=1 \implies a^p=a\implies a^p-a=0 $ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Hence, $ p$ divides $ a^p-a$ .